# Checking for overlapping TimeField ranges

Tags: python-2.7, django-1.11

I have this model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("campaign_id", "task_start", "task_end", "task_day")

    campaign_id = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    playlist_id = models.ForeignKey(PlayList, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    task_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    task_start = models.TimeField()
    task_end = models.TimeField()
    task_day = models.TextField()
```

I need to write a validation test that checks if a newly created task time range overlaps with an existing one in the database.

For example:

A task with and ID 1 already has a starting time at 5:00PM and ends at 5:15PM on a Saturday. A new task cannot be created between the first task's start and end time. Where should I write this test and what is the most efficent way to do this? I also use DjangoRestFramework Serializers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you receive the form data from the user, you can:

- Check the fields are consistent: user *task_start* < user *task_end*, and warn the user if not.
- Query (SELECT) the database to retrieve all existing tasks which intercept the user time,

  - Order the records by *task_start* (ORDER BY),
  - Select only records which validate your criterion, a.k.a.:

    - *task_start* <= user *task_start* <= *task_end*, or,
    - *task_start* <= user *task_end* <= *task_end*.
  - warn the user if at least one record is found.
- Everything is OK:

  - Construct a `Task` instance,
  - Store it in database.
  - Return success.

Implementation details:

*task_start* and *task_end* could be indexed in your database to improve selection time.

I saw that you also have a *task_day* field (which is a TEXT).

You should really consider using UTC DATETIME fields instead of TEXT, because you need to compare date AND time (and not only time): consider a task which starts at 23:30 and finish at 00:45 the day after…

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it. It's not optimal by far, but I'm limited to python 2.7 and Django 1.11 and I'm also a beginner.

```
def validate(self, data):
    errors = {}
    task_start = data.get('task_start')
    task_end = data.get('task_end')
    time_filter = Q(task_start__range=[task_start, task_end]) 
    | Q(task_end__range=[task_start, task_end])
    filter_check = Task.objects.filter(time_filter).exists()
    if task_start > task_end:
        errors['error'] = u'End time cannot be earlier than start time!'
        raise serializers.ValidationError(errors)
    elif filter_check:
        errors['errors'] = u'Overlapping tasks'
        raise serializers.ValidationError(errors)
    else:
        pass
    return data
```